# How to Hide Next Button in QT Wizard

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with a `QWizard` that really should've been implemented as a `QStackedWidget` but it's too far gone to change now. I have a `QPushButton` I would like to call a SLOT from, and that SLOT then calls `nextId()` after doing other things.

I have tried removing the next button with:

```
QList<QWizard::WizardButton> wizardButtons;
wizardButtons << QWizard::Stretch << QWizard::BackButton << QWizard::FinishButton << QWizard::CancelButton;
wizard()->setButtonLayout(wizardButtons);
```

This worked to remove the button, but now `nextId()` doesn't transition to another page of the wizard.

I also tried

```
wizard()->button(QWizardButton::NextButton)->hide();
```

But that didn't have any effect

> How can I hide the next button so I am still able to transition pages when my `QPushButton` in the top right is clicked? Or is there a way to force the wizard to my desired page without the next button?

This GUI was done programatically, I cannot just use creator.

This is the desired layout
[image: desired layout]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I was able to call

```
wizard()->next();
```

from the SLOT which forced a call to `nextId()`.

This is probably not the best way to handle this but it is working. I will accept another answer if one is presented, or alterations/comments on the validity of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,

```
QAbstractButton *nextButton = wizard()->button(QWizard::NextButton);
nextButton->setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent; width: 0px; height: 0px;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think calling `next()` is the right way to proceed to the next page.

There may not be an elegant way to hide the next button but you can disable it:  Override `QWizardPage::isComplete()` to return false whenever you want the next/finish button to be disabled.  Emit `completeChanged()` whenever `isComplete()` needs to be be reevaluated.

```
MyWizardPage::MyWizardPage(QWidget * parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MyWizardPage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Emit completeChanged() whenever the email field changes.
    connect(ui->email, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SIGNAL(completeChanged()));
}

bool MyWizardPage::isComplete() const
{
    // Enable the next/finish button when email has more than 5 chars
    return ui->email->text().length() > 5
}
```

To keep the next button disabled all the time just always return false from `isComplete()` and don't worry about ever emitting `completeChanged()`.